# Send email reports automatically

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am using excel for reports. I have  a requirement to send these reports as emails automatically, Is there a feature in excel that helps in this?

I have used power BI before but Can this be done in power BI?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+send+email+vba

Comment: Thanks, but does it send emails automatically? In the sample the email is sent on command button. I want the emails to be sent everyday at a particular time without me having to do any manual work.

Comment: If you want it to be sent at a specific time then you can use `Application.OnTime` (if your workbook will be open at that time) or Windows Task Scheduler (assuming you're on Windows). You're going to have to do a bit of programming to make this happen.  Do some Googling then post back if you have specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

For scheduled reports, you can use [Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx). RS can generate Excel files as output. Might not be exactly what you're looking for.